A few records are missing when writing to a avro file using Spark
While writing an avro file on hdfs, a few records are getting dropped.
This happens occasionally. The data in dataset is flat, not nested, still sometimes some
records are dropped while writing.
What could be the reason?

Invalid schema could be a reason, corrupt record.
